# IE messing up my sorted EmberJS ArrayProxy

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ember.js

Could someone please have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/tur9b/9/

It's a simple ordered list. You can remove a list entry by clicking on the name.

IE (tested in IE9) shows strange behavior. Currently I have no clue at all whats wrong there.

Comment: Can you give a little more info on what's going wrong? I don't have IE9, but I might be able to provide some insight if you were to explain the problem.

Comment: Ok, normally you would see a list of Names in alphabetical order and by clicking the name, it simply disappears. In IE you see that exact same list: "Bob, Gary Joe, John, Justin, Peter, Steve". By clicking "Bob" the list looks like this: "Gary, Steve, Peter, Justin, John, Joe". When I then click Joe, it simply swaps Joe to Steve (which is now duplicated)... very disturbing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be fixed when using ember-latest:

http://jsfiddle.net/dgeb/3DvbT/1/

I'm pretty sure the problem was fixed with this commit:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/8f5abce7f0f27190596658a5b6a71631a282a6c6